# How do I integrate SMF into my custom Php member based website?

Tags: php, open-source, simple-machines-forum

I built a simple social community website for a client - the client would like to add in a forum and he likes Simple Machines Forum. The website I built has its own users management system. The client would like SMF on his website and at the same time when a user is logged into the website they don't need to log into SMF website as well... how can this be done? Or should I just tell the client to consider two separet independant applications in this case i.e forum totally disjoint from the main site?

Comment: I think an SMF support forum is probably a better source of advice for this question. Though I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: Yeah but I'm pretty much under the assumption that you can ask and get an answer to almost anything on Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMF has an API available and there are bridges for several popular CMS on the SMF site.

You would have to build a bridge for your community site or use an existing one if your site's CMS already has one.

[SMF CMS Bridges](http://download.simplemachines.org/?bridges)

[SMF API](http://download.simplemachines.org/?tools)